# VueJs: How to create a select where options come from a query to other model

Tags: laravel, select, vue.js

I'm new on VueJs and I don't know why I have the following problem:

I'm creating a view called Owners.vue where I show pub owners. In UpdateProfile.vue I show the owner data and here is where I have my problem: I'd like to build a select where the options are the possible pubs stored in my table "pubs":

My vue component is as follows:

### UpdateProfile.vue

```
<template>

<confirm title="Edit User" ok="Save user" :show="show"
         v-on:save="save"
         v-on:close="close">

    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Name</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="User name" v-model="data.name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Lastname</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="last name" v-model="data.lastname">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Email</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="email" v-model="data.email">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Owner Pubs-->
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Pubs</label>
        <div v-for="pub in data.userPubsOwned" class="control">
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Pub tapps" v-model="pub.name">
            <div class="button is-danger" @click="deletePubFromOwner(pub.id)">
                <span class="icon"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <!--Owner Pubs-->

    <!--Add Pubs to Owner-->
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Add new Pub</label>
        <div class="select">
            <select v-model="pubs">
                <option v-for = "pub in pubs" :value="pub.id" >{{pub.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="button is-info" @click="addPubToOwner()">
            <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-save fa-lg"></i></span>
            <span>Add Tapp</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Add Pubs to Owner-->

</confirm>
```

```
import User from "../../models/user";

export default {

    props: {
        show: Boolean,
        data: Object,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            selected: null,
            data: new User(),
            pubs: [],
            pub: new Pub(),
        }
    },

    computed: {

    },

    methods: {
        save() {
            this.$emit('save', this.data);
        },
        close() {
            this.$emit('close');
        },
        hasRootPermissionsAndIsNotRoot() {
            return this.CONSTANTS.hasRootPermissions() && this.data.permissions !== this.CONSTANTS.ROOT_USER.permissions;
        },
        addPubToOwner(){
            this.api.post('/owners/' + this.data.id + '/' + this.selected).then(response => {
                this.data = response.data;
            });
        },
        deletePubFromOwner(ownerpub) {
            this.api.delete('/owners/' + this.data.id + '/' + ownerpub).then(response => {
                this.data = response.data;
            });
        },
    }
}
```

I just need to show all the pubs stored in my table pub...do I have to create a function? And how it would be?

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Do you use `VueRouter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create a method in the mounted() section. I use a similar process to show all of the flavors/prices of a product in a shopping cart. Here is my code that you can use and hopefully extrapolate your answer from:

Mounted function to load upon vue mount

```
 mounted: function() {
    this.getPrice();
     },
```

getPrice() function:

```
 getPrice: function(){
         axios.post('/getproductinfo', this.$data.model)
             .then((response) => {
                 console.log(response);
                 this.display_name = response.data.display_name;
                 this.price = '$' + response.data.price;
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors);
             });
     },
```

And finally the code in your view blade file

```
<select class="centerSelect" v-show="!loading && ordering" ref="quantitySelect" v-model="model.id" name="code_id" @change="getPrice">
@foreach ($code as $item)
<option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->display_name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```